# Select row of a matrix by finding the requested value in the first column

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to write a code in Fortran that allows to select data from a matrix of random walks (at one specific step) and select the vector of that specific value. In the first column of the matrix I have the time and in the next ones I have the w-th walker.

Here is my code. The issue is that I’m not able to write the vector (row) that I want to select based on the value that is written in the first column of the matrix. The problem is that the code doesn’t select the chosen row based on the value that is written in the first column of the matrix.

```
program walker
implicit none
integer ::   n_seed
integer :: i, t, time, n_time, n_walker,m
real :: space,  n_count, y, step
real, allocatable, dimension (:,:):: walk !matrix (time,walker)
real, allocatable, dimension (:,:):: spacex !spacex (time,walker)

print*,"Enter number of walkers  (integer)"
read*,n_walker

print*,"Enter total steps number (integer) (s)"
read*,n_time

print*,"Enter lenght of single step (real)"
read*,step
m=1
n_walker=n_walker+1

allocate(walk(n_time,n_walker))
allocate(spacex(n_walker,m))

open(unit=8, file='walk.dat', status='unknown')

do t=1, n_time   !!!!!!!!!!!!!to write the first column as progressive number of temporal step
do i=1, n_walker
if (i.eq.1) then
walk(t,i)=t
else
walk(t,i)=0.
end if
end do
end do

call system_clock(count=time)
n_seed=time+(23)**2

call srand(n_seed)



 do t=2, n_time
do i=2, n_walker !first loop is 2 due the temporal count column 
y=rand()
if (y.lt.0.5) then
walk(t,i)=walk(t-1,i)+step
else
walk(t,i)=walk(t-1,i)-step
end if
    
end do
 end do


 do t=1, n_time 

write (8,*) (walk(t,i),i=1, n_walker)

end do

 rewind(8)

 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!the issue is in the following instruction!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 do t=1, n_time 
 read (8,*) (walk(t,i),i=1, n_walker)

 if (walk(t,1).eq.4.) then
do i=1, n_walker
write(*,*) spacex(i,1)
end do

end if
end do

end program walker`your text``
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. What exactly does "the issue is that I-m not able to write the vector that I want to selcet." mean? What happens? Is there any error message? Or what exactly happens? Something wrong is printed? What exactly?

Comment: Second @VladimirFГероямслава . I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Please *edit the question* to clarify this.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t speak English so well. I want the select an entire row from a matrix, in base of a value that is into the first column. Thanks

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean. Please show exactly what happens. Show the program input and the program output. Copy and paste it exactly from your terminal. Tell us, which output you would like to see instead. Also, I really suggest to visit the links I gave in my first comment.

Comment: `mat` is a 2D array, `v` the value you want to find in the first colum: `irow = findloc(mat(:,1),dim=1)` is the index of the row that contains `v`, and `mat(irow,:)` is the entire row.

Comment: @PierU your advice solved my issue with the code. I really appreciate your help. Apparently you are able to read my mind since my post appears to be incomprehensible Thank you

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Sorry if I didn,t follow exactly the  posting rules in this forum. I will read carefully the guide. cheers

Comment: It is not about the rules at this point, it is about giving enough information so that someone can actually identify the problem and answer. Try to help people you are asking for help, do not just follow some rules. Often one can somehow guess what was meant, but often it means one has to devote more time to play with the code than it would be necessary otherwise. When I write that I do not understand the description of the problem, I mean it truly and honestly.

Comment: I hooe I understood the problem correctly. Your design to store the times and the walk data in one array is not strictly wrong but I would suggest to separate the data into separate arrays. One 1D array for the times and one 2D array ("matrix") for the walk data. It makes the structure clearer.